# Why do maximum line lengths sometimes end with 9?

Tags: conventions, pep8

In some conventions, [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) for example, I see maximum line widths recommended to be set to values ending with `9`, such as 79, 99, 119. Why not rounded to 10, like 80, 100, 120?

I feel like it's an off-by-one error I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegedly from GvR himself, from an [r/learnpython thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1h2eug/pep_8_why_is_the_character_limit_79_and_not_80/):

> One person suggested that 79 character code allows for a + or - for diffs in windows that are limited to 80 characters.
> While that is certainly true, I wasn't sure that this was the answer, so I e-mailed the authors of the PEP 8 document and got this reply back from Guido van Rossum just over an hour after I sent the e-mail:
>
> > Because an 80 char wide Emacs window starts wrapping at 79.